# Windows phone embedded 8 ClaimedBarcodeScanner.DataReceived

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, barcode-scanner, windows-embedded-8

I'm trying to interact with the scanner of the "Honeywell Dolphin CT50" with windows embedded 8. This is the code snipped I used, to activate the integrated barcodescanner but it isn't working as expected, the DataReceived method never gets called.

By the way, the Barcodescanner example application, which is installed on the Device is working, so it can't be a problem with the barcodes or the scanner itself.

```
    Dim c As DeviceInformationCollection = Await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector())
    Dim scanner As BarcodeScanner = Await BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(c(0).Id)
    Me._scanner = Await scanner.ClaimScannerAsync()
    AddHandler Me._scanner.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceived
```

Comment: Read the notes about the package manifest file in [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792060%28v=winembedded.81%29.aspx), it won't work without it.

Comment: Adding <DeviceCapability Name="PointofService"/> to my Package.appxmanifest, causes this error, when running the application:

Comment: Package could not be registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)

Comment: Okay, so you know now why it did not work, the DeviceCapability is *required*.  You now have completely different question, click the Ask Question button to document it.